# Perform actions on field collection insert or update

Tags: 7, hooks, entities

I have created field collection and added it to my content type. I have created a node, and now user can add field collections on this node. But i need to write into a file(some stuff) when user `added` new field collection or updated it. I need something like `hook_node_insert` and `hook_node_update`, i cant find anything for field collection.

In preprocess_node i have outputed `field_collection_field` and its returns only `ids`, and i can get them only by this code:

```
 $field_ids = array();
            //context_node = my current node,
            //field_block_id == field collection field
            foreach ($context_node->field_block_id['und'] as $element) {
                $field_ids[] = $element['value'];
            }
 $field_collection = entity_load('field_collection_item', $field_ids);
```

Comment: Did you `dpm($node);` your hook_node_insert ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Field Collection Item is an entity, so the equivalents of the node hooks are [`hook_entity_insert()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/7)

> Act on entities when inserted.

And [`hook_entity_update()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_update/7)

> Act on entities when updated.

Comment: this is what i am looking for

Answer (score 3):

the field collection APIs are defined in the `field_collection.api.php`

The hook function that would interest you is hook_field_collection_item_presave()

```
/**
 * Acts on a field collection item being inserted or updated.
 *
 * This hook is invoked before the field collection item is saved to the database.
 *
 * @param FieldCollectionItemEntity $field_collection_item
 *   The field collection item that is being inserted or updated.
 *
 * @see hook_entity_presave()
 */
function hook_field_collection_item_presave(FieldCollectionItemEntity $field_collection_item) {
  $field_collection_item->name = 'foo';
}
```