# theming field collection in node add form

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I have themed node/add form of a special content type using the following instruction:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1092122

and I have changed this form to a table.

Now I'm struggling with a field collection with unlimited number of item.
As I have hidden the default form of displaying node/add form when I click on 'add another item' of the field collection, nothing happens.

What I want is to show the next form of the field collection as the next row of the table ready for the user to fill it out.

Any help would be appreciated.
thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to hook into the field collection entity on insert, and add a callback function to trigger the new row to appear via ajax in your table.

Check out `field_collection.api.php` in the [field collection module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) for a full list of field collection api calls/methods.

Also, you may find the responses to this previous post as a good indicator of the direction to take: [Perform actions on field collection insert or update](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59217/perform-actions-on-field-collection-insert-or-update)

Comment: the problem is in the previous step of inserting. I don't have a form to fill and submit. I just want to show the form of new field collection entity as a table.